# Index out of range in Python while finding tr tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to crawl the below data.
And the problem is that I don't know how many `tr` is in the website so I just said `range(0, 24)`. However I am pretty sure that it has at least 24. But the code still says it's out of range.

How do I crawl this website and get all the information (the bilingual text), even if I don't know how many rows there are?

Below is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/"

html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

gdp_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "table-translations"})
gdp_table_data = gdp_table.tbody.find_all("tr")  # contains # rows

for i in range(0, 24):
    for td in gdp_table_data[i].find_all("td"):
        headings = []
        headings.append(td.get_text(strip=True))
        print(headings[1], " | ", headings[2])
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using: for tr in gdp_table.find_all("tr") ?

Answer (score 0):

You already iterate over each element in `gdp_table_data[i].find_all("td")`. Use the same idea for the row iteration

```
for tr in gdp_table_data:
    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the best solution to save it as a csv:

```
import pandas as  pd

dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/')
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_csv('a.csv')
```

saves a csv file (`a.csv`) with the data.

---

Or only printing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r =requests.get('http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
trs = soup.select('table.table-translations tr')
for tr in trs:
    print(tr.get_text())
```

prints:

```
No.
Mongolian text
Loosely translated into English


1.
Зургаан мөнгөн мичид
Six silver stars


2.
Эрт урьд цагт зургаан өнчин хүүхэд товцог толгой дээр наадан суудаг юм санжээ.
Long ago, there were six orphan brothers playing on the top of a hill.



Тэгсэн чинь ах нь нэг өдөр хэлж:
One day the oldest brother said:
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This script will write all translations to `data.csv`:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'http://www.mongols.eu/mongolian-language/mongolian-tale-six-silver-stars/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('.table-translations tr')[1:]:
    mongolian, english = map(lambda t: t.get_text(strip=True), row.select('td')[1:])
    all_data.append((mongolian, english))

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Creates:

[image]